# jQuery time difference of utc offSets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find time difference between user's time and server side time. Like what time is user having on his system and what's the value coming from database. I have got it approximately.

But now my problem is what if user is from difference time zone rather then the value is coming from database? So now I want to find the exact difference by managing their time zones. Here I am putting my sample code and the values I am getting with their formats.

```
    var studentSessionStartTimeDate = that._sessionData.studentSession.dtStart; //date with time from db
    var splitTimeDate = studentSessionStartTimeDate.split(' ');
    var oldDate = splitTimeDate[0]; // split date different
    var dateold = new Date(oldDate).getTime(); //convert date into milliseconds
    var time=that._sessionData.studentSession.start;  // User's exact start time from db
    var convertedTime=(Number(time.split(':')[0])*60+Number(time.split(':')[1]))*1000;  // converted time in milliseconds
    var sessionStartTime = dateold+convertedTime;  // db time and date value in milliseconds
    var systemTime = new Date().getTime();   // user's system time value in milliseconds
    var timeDiff = sessionStartTime - systemTime; // now i want this time diff to be exact but it is not calculating the zone difference
```

Now if someone want I can get utc Offset from db also, but how can I get difference?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

you could get browser time zone with following code:

new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

Comment: yes i know this. but i am not able to write code for this particular part where i can manage there utc calculation